# Einstein Bot with apex invocable action

Tags: einstein

Can I call two different classes with invocable methods as apex action in einstein bot? I have created two classes and calling them in different dialogs but only first method is showing. can anybody explain?

Comment: I found that it sometimes takes a while for the system to propagate addition of invocable methods so they appear in the tooling UI. How long ago did you add the second class and method? Did you correctly annotate the second method and any parameter class (if you have one)?

Comment: It would be much better if your question included snippets of your code. Take a look at [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance in asking questions to get answers. You can [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/278708/edit) your question to add in the detail.

Comment: @phil w I have added it 4 hours ago..

Comment: I don't see anything extra added here. Did you create a second question? If so, please delete this one.

Comment: make sure you have run tests on the invocable class(es)